# Prevent specific label class from being affected by JS function

Tags: javascript

I have a script which is used to position text field labels at the top of the field on focus.
My issue is that this script is also affecting other labels in the same form where it is not required.

I did some reading on SO and saw reference to :not, but I couldn't figure out how to use it in my context based on the examples I found.

This is my script

```
$(function(){
var onClass = "on";
var showClass = "show";

$("input").bind("checkval",function(){
var label = $(this).prev("label");
if(this.value !== ""){
  label.addClass(showClass);
} else {
  label.removeClass(showClass);
}
}).on("keyup",function(){
  $(this).trigger("checkval");
}).on("focus",function(){
  $(this).prev("label").addClass(onClass);
}).on("blur",function(){
    $(this).prev("label").removeClass(onClass);
}).trigger("checkval");
});
```

I've added a class to these affected labels.

```
<label class="ignoreLabel">
```

and now I need to make the script ignore labels with this class.

Comment: `if (!label.hasClass("ignoreClass"))...`

Comment: @ChrisG That worked, after I changed the class name ;) Thanks. So that I learn from this, if I had a similar thing to do on a span, it would have been !span.hasClass, correct?

Comment: As long as whatever you have before `.hasClass` is a jQuery object, yes. Btw, I recommend adding a `$` to distinguish them: `var $label = $(this).prev("label");` This way it's immediately obvious that `$label` is a jQuery object.